# Convert a human date to unix timestamp

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I have a jQuery script that returns a date as:

Wed Nov 09 2011 16:30:00 GMT-0700 (MST)

How could I convert that into unix timestamp? I was looking at mktime() but I'm not really understanding it completely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.2, try the `DateTime` class, eg

```
$dt = new DateTime("Wed Nov 09 2011 16:30:00 GMT-0700 (MST)");
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
```

Otherwise, try [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), eg

```
$ts = strtotime("Wed Nov 09 2011 16:30:00 GMT-0700 (MST)");
echo date("r", $ts);
```

For me, this outputs

> Thu, 10 Nov 2011 10:30:00 +1100

Note that the `date()` function is local timezone aware

Comment: I find this function often gets overlooked because it's actually quite powerful; it's definitely far more capable than one might expect if they're new to scripting, or just new to PHP. It's not perfect, but it's a very cool function.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that jQuery's using a Date object; instead, have the script send the value of `Math.floor(theDate.getTime() / 1000)` to your PHP script. That's the Unix timestamp you need.

Answer (score 1):

What about [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) ?

```
$test = strtotime('Wed Nov 09 2011 16:30:00 GMT-0700 (MST)');

echo $test;

output : 1320881400
```